# Prove that $I-T$ is an isomorphism if $T:V \to V$ and $T^3=0$ and find $(I-T)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Given a linear map of finite dimension $T:V \to V$ and $T^3=0$ and $\exists v \in V| T^2(v) \neq 0$ prove that $I-T$ is an isomorphism and find $(I-T)^{-1}$.

We can think of the identity $(I-T^3)=(I-T)(I+T+T^2)$ and because $T^3=0$ then $(I-T)(I+T+T^2)=I$ therefore $I-T$ is invertible and $(I-T)^{-1}=(I+T+T^2)$.

This means that $\text{ker}T=\{0\}$ because for any $v \in V$ there's only the trivial solution to $Ax=v$.

My **question** is because the linear map is not actually defined (we don't know if it's $\mathbb F^n\to \mathbb F^m$) how do we know that the matrix $A$ exists such that $Ax=v$? Is it because we're guaranteed a unique representation matrix for any linear map?

Comment: Yes, any linear transformation has a matrix representation once you fix bases of the domain and codomain.

Comment: Your solution is correct, a linear map gives you a matrix.

Comment: You also did not make explicit where you used the fact that there is a vector $v$ such that $T^2v$ is nonzero. Your argument would be better if you made this explicit.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I didn't use the fact because I didn't think we need it. There're more subquestions to this question and one of them uses the fact that $T^2(v) \neq 0$. I included the fact because I wasn't sure if we need it for this question

Comment: $\ker T=\{0\}$ is wrong (unless $V=\{0\}$), because of $T^3=0$.

Comment: @Arthur but if the kernel contains non-zero vectors then there're non-trivial solutions to $Ax=v$, but $A$ is invertible?

Comment: You need to be specific about what $A$ is. $I-T$ is invertible, and $(I-T)x=0$ has only the trivial solution. However, $T$ is not invertible, and $Tx=0$ has non-trivial solutions.

Comment: @Arthur sorry I meant $\text{ker}(I-T)=\{0\}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need no matrix. Your computation is right:
$$
(I-T)(I+T+T^2)=I-T+T-T^2+T^2-T^3=I
$$
so $(I-T)^{-1}=I+T+T^2$. Since also $(I+T+T^2)(I-T)=I$, you don't even have to invoke finite dimension in order to conclude $I-T$ is an isomorphism, because you found its inverse.

The assumption that $T^2\ne0$ is redundant. It can be used to show that, if $\dim V=3$, then $\{v,T(v),T^2(v)\}$ is a basis of $V$ as soon as $T^2(v)\ne0$.

Note also that $\ker T\ne\{0\}$, otherwise $T$ would be injective (and surjective in case $V$ is finite dimensional) and $T^3\ne0$.

Comment: You guessed exactly correct that one of the subquestions asked to prove that $v, T(v), T^2(v)$ is linearly independent! Although we did have a theorem that if a matrix has an inverse it is an isomorphism but I wanted to understand what my matrix is. $I$ is of course a matrix but regarding the linear map $T$ as far as I understand we have a corresponding matrix because each transformationis guaranteed a matrix representation. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @Yos Until you're not given a basis, you can't write down a matrix.

Comment: Yes but I know it exists?

Comment: @Yos Every finite dimensional vector space has a basis.